# How to include subtitles in Azure Media Services' manifest?

Tags: azure-media-services

Using the portal I uploaded a video to an input-asset and encoded it into an output-asset. On the output-asset I uploaded a .vtt file via "Upload captions" button. I can reproduce the video with the captions/subtitles in https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/, using the manifest URL and an extra URL for the .vtt file in the "Tracks" options. However other video players don't seem to support captions/subtitles via an extra URL (for example in Android or [here](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test)). Is there a way to somehow include the captions/subtitles in the manifest? I see manifests from other sources including subtitles. For example, https://d3rlna7iyyu8wu.cloudfront.net/skip_armstrong/skip_armstrong_stereo_subs.m3u8 (can be played [here](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way to add the captions to the manifest itself.  However, you pointed to the Bitmovin player and it actually supports VTT captions as per https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/articles/subtitle-and-closed-captions-support.  Here's some example code that includes the VTT link https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/web/8/docs/interfaces/core_config.sourceconfig.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Bitmovin was just a web example, my real case is to play in Android and iOS. The respective developers found a way to work with an external subtitles URL, but it was tricky. It would be more straight forward if it would be possible to have the subtitles URL within the manifest.